# DDMS heap checker is not working

Tags: android, performance, heap-memory

[image: DDMS screen shot]

The questions are in the image. I have installed the drivers etc. The same thing is seen when i try to use the heap checker in Eclipse. The log-cat is working fine.

Thanks - Akash

Comment: Check if you are debugging or just running. Also perhaps you have to select the process to enable the butons.

Comment: @pankaj Should i check the same thing on the emulator? Is that what you are asking. This screen shot is of a device (HTC_Desire) connected.

Comment: @Smith The process should be shown below the device name right? Where I'm currently seeing com.google.android.apps.upload? My app dosen't show up there. Or is there anywhere else i need to select the process?

Comment: Ok, so you have to select your application. For example com.google.android.apps......

Comment: But I don't see my application in the list :(, any other way to check it?

Comment: Ran the app on the avd, can see my app and also heap usage. Nice. Can you tell me what the "Grow Heap(frag case)" signifies? Thanks